# How to convert value of Length Seconds in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

This is video Length in seconds : `145`

and i want to out put this value like this `,80,74,2,` How can i get Length Seconds `145` to Convert like `,80,74,2,` in PHP
`{"length_seconds":"145"}` how to i covert `length_seconds 145` in this format `80,74,2`
For this example JavaScript

```
videojs('mint').thumbnails(eval("("+mksb('G_0TziI12SE',80,74,2,'wa1cIFpwGxMNbz9bRlRFZCkjlOc')+")"));
```

Comment: How do you get `80,74,2` from `145`?

Comment: @Barmar This is a Youtube video ID `G_0TziI12SE` This is Length of video is `145` and i get this `80,74,2` from this URL embed source `view-source:https://s.ytapi.com/embed/G_0TziI12SE`

Comment: I can't figure out any relationship between these values. Do you know anything more about it?

Comment: @Will Please visit this URL and check the source code `https://s.ytapi.com/embed/G_0TziI12SE` and you find this `videojs('mint').thumbnails(eval("("+mksb('G_0TziI12SE',80,74,2,'wa1cIFpwGxMNbz9bRlRFZCkjlOc')+")"));` and this video Real length in second is `145`

Comment: Well I see it but I don't understand how that corresponds to  `145` in any possible way.

Comment: @Will i'm trying this `145/2=72.5` and then `145/3=48` but this very difference

Answer (score 1):

Alright, by digging through the source code, I found `mksb()` in [videojs.thumbnails.js](https://s.ytapi.com/players/videojs/videojs.thumbnails.js):

```
function mksb(vid, img_width, frames, interval, sihg) {
    var r = '';
    counter = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (counter == frames) break;
                x1 = img_width * i;
                x2 = x1 + 40;
                x3 = x1 + 80;
                y1 = j * 45;
                y2 = y1 + 60;
                y3 = y1 + 45;
                x4 = frames - k * 100;
                if (x4 < 100) {
                    x4 = Math.ceil(x4 / 10) * 45;
                } else {
                    x4 = 450;
                };
                m = '//img.ytapi.com/sb/' + vid + '/storyboard3_L1/M' + k + '.jpg?sigh=' + sihg;
                r += counter++ * interval + ":{src:'" + m + "',style:{left:'-" + x2 + "px',width:'" + img_width * 10;
                r += "px',height:'" + x4 + "px',top:'-" + y2 + "px',clip:'rect(" + y1 + "px," + x3 + "px," + y3 + "px," + x1 + "px)'}},";
            }
        }
    }
    return '{' + r + '}';
}
```

So, `'G_0TziI12SE'` is the video ID, `80` is the thumbnail width, `74` seems to be a frame count, `2` seems to be an interval in seconds, and I have no idea what `'wa1cIFpwGxMNbz9‌​bRlRFZCkjlOc'` is, but perhaps a cryptographic signature?

So, `74 * 2` is 148, which is fairly close to `145`, but that's as close as I can get. This basically seems to be a "frames @ frame-rate" type of expression. So, to convert seconds into this type of expression, you'd just do `(int) $seconds / 2`.

That's all I've got, but I hope it helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for my help and one question what do you thing about this `80,208,10` and this video id is `sC4n9BcwkGQ` and URL is `https://s.ytapi.com/embed/sC4n9BcwkGQ`

Comment: `sC4n9BcwkGQ` this video id length is 2064

Comment: i get this url `http://i.ytimg.com/sb/sVBy17B945w/storyboard3_L$L/$N.jpg|48#27#100#10#10#0#default#ntkbPG_bo3RUbQs4U4cGJSbpNWQ|79#45#597#10#10#10000#M$M#bCKxfTV87smEuN_czEZegTHX7Zc|158#90#597#5#5#10000#M$M#fy8oaHr1l-Lk7jEtSVxG1tFIL80` check | of secod `img_width 79, frames 597 and interval 10 and sigh bCKxfTV87smEuN_czEZegTHX7Zc`